# MediaElement rotated video xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I have a player that contains a MediaElement , in xaml,
When i play some videos (created by phone) they are displayed upside down or rotated wrong.

Normal players display the video correctly.

What's the issue?
Is possbile to fix it using mediaelement?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
    <MediaElement.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
    </MediaElement.RenderTransform>
</MediaElement>
```

Comment: Problem was... Need to know when is rotate not how to rotate